# ts-jest disable babel, babel still appears to be running

Tags: node.js, jestjs, yarnpkg, babel-jest, yarnpkg-v2

So the [docs say](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/babelConfig) it should not be; but I'm seeing this output.

```
➤ YN0000: [@bb/graph]: [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /home/runner/work/services/services/.pnp.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
```

```
> yarn info -A '*babel-*'                                               # services -> feature/RS2-1243-logging $ !
├─ babel-jest@npm:26.5.2
│  ├─ Instances: 1
│  ├─ Version: 26.5.2
│  │
│  └─ Dependencies
│     ├─ @jest/transform@npm:^26.5.2 → npm:26.5.2
│     ├─ @jest/types@npm:^26.5.2 → npm:26.5.2
│     ├─ @types/babel__core@npm:^7.1.7 → npm:7.1.9
│     ├─ babel-plugin-istanbul@npm:^6.0.0 → npm:6.0.0
│     ├─ babel-preset-jest@npm:^26.5.0 → npm:26.5.0
│     ├─ chalk@npm:^4.0.0 → npm:4.1.0
│     ├─ graceful-fs@npm:^4.2.4 → npm:4.2.4
│     └─ slash@npm:^3.0.0 → npm:3.0.0
│
├─ babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node@npm:2.3.3
│  ├─ Version: 2.3.3
│  │
│  └─ Dependencies
│     └─ object.assign@npm:^4.1.0 → npm:4.1.0
│
├─ babel-plugin-istanbul@npm:6.0.0
│  ├─ Version: 6.0.0
│  │
│  └─ Dependencies
│     ├─ @babel/helper-plugin-utils@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @istanbuljs/load-nyc-config@npm:^1.0.0 → npm:1.1.0
│     ├─ @istanbuljs/schema@npm:^0.1.2 → npm:0.1.2
│     ├─ istanbul-lib-instrument@npm:^4.0.0 → npm:4.0.3
│     └─ test-exclude@npm:^6.0.0 → npm:6.0.0
│
├─ babel-plugin-jest-hoist@npm:26.5.0
│  ├─ Version: 26.5.0
│  │
│  └─ Dependencies
│     ├─ @babel/template@npm:^7.3.3 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/types@npm:^7.3.3 → npm:7.11.5
│     ├─ @types/babel__core@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.1.9
│     └─ @types/babel__traverse@npm:^7.0.6 → npm:7.0.13
│
├─ babel-plugin-syntax-trailing-function-commas@npm:7.0.0-beta.0
│  └─ Version: 7.0.0-beta.0
│
├─ babel-preset-current-node-syntax@npm:0.1.3
│  ├─ Instances: 1
│  ├─ Version: 0.1.3
│  │
│  └─ Dependencies
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-async-generators@npm:^7.8.4 → npm:7.8.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-bigint@npm:^7.8.3 → npm:7.8.3
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties@npm:^7.8.3 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta@npm:^7.8.3 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-json-strings@npm:^7.8.3 → npm:7.8.3
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-logical-assignment-operators@npm:^7.8.3 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator@npm:^7.8.3 → npm:7.8.3
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-numeric-separator@npm:^7.8.3 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@npm:^7.8.3 → npm:7.8.3
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding@npm:^7.8.3 → npm:7.8.3
│     └─ @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining@npm:^7.8.3 → npm:7.8.3
│
├─ babel-preset-fbjs@npm:3.3.0
│  ├─ Instances: 1
│  ├─ Version: 3.3.0
│  │
│  └─ Dependencies
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.11.0
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-flow@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.8.3
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoped-functions@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.11.1
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-classes@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-destructuring@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-for-of@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-function-name@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-literals@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-member-expression-literals@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-object-super@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-parameters@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.5
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-property-literals@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.4
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-spread@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.11.0
│     ├─ @babel/plugin-transform-template-literals@npm:^7.0.0 → npm:7.10.5
│     └─ babel-plugin-syntax-trailing-function-commas@npm:^7.0.0-beta.0 → npm:7.0.0-beta.0
│
└─ babel-preset-jest@npm:26.5.0
   ├─ Instances: 1
   ├─ Version: 26.5.0
   │
   └─ Dependencies
      ├─ babel-plugin-jest-hoist@npm:^26.5.0 → npm:26.5.0
      └─ babel-preset-current-node-syntax@npm:^0.1.3 → npm:0.1.3
```

```
> yarn why -R 'babel-jest'                                              # services -> feature/RS2-1243-logging $ !
├─ @bb/apollo-test-util@workspace:app-lib/graph/packages/apollo-test-util
│  └─ jest@npm:26.5.2 (via npm:^26.5.2)
│     ├─ @jest/core@npm:26.5.2 (via npm:^26.5.2)
│     │  └─ jest-config@npm:26.5.2 (via npm:^26.5.2)
│     │     └─ babel-jest@npm:26.5.2 [dc086] (via npm:^26.5.2 [dc086])
│     └─ jest-cli@npm:26.5.2 (via npm:^26.5.2)
│        ├─ @jest/core@npm:26.5.2 (via npm:^26.5.2)
│        └─ jest-config@npm:26.5.2 (via npm:^26.5.2)
│
├─ @bb/app-lib@workspace:app-lib
│  └─ jest@npm:26.5.2 (via npm:^26.5.2)
│
├─ @bb/graph@workspace:app-lib/graph/packages/app
│  ├─ @bb/apollo-test-util@workspace:app-lib/graph/packages/apollo-test-util (via workspace:app-lib/graph/packages/apollo-test-util)
│  └─ jest@npm:26.5.2 (via npm:^26.5.2)
│
└─ @bb/test-apollo-configuration@workspace:app-lib/graph/packages/test-apollo-configuration
   └─ @bb/apollo-test-util@workspace:app-lib/graph/packages/apollo-test-util (via workspace:app-lib/graph/packages/
```

is there any way with yarn2 I can just remove babel safely? or barring that completely prevent it from running?